# Gmail API's Java integration issue

Tags: java, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I'm involved in a develop that lead me to integrate Gmail API in my Java project.

Like everybody I started my test bringing the [GmailQuickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) example provided in the official documentation.

I perform a few test on it but I'm not able to login and list labels of my account.

This is my class :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Label;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListLabelsResponse;

public class ComunicoTestSergio {

    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/ComunicoTestSergio.json");
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME ="comunico";

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = ComunicoTestSergio.class.getResourceAsStream(
                "/comunico-test-sergio-client_secret_113926736970383780927.json");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, isr);           
        Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport( HTTP_TRANSPORT )
                .setJsonFactory( JSON_FACTORY )
                .setServiceAccountId( "comunico-test-sergio comunico-test-sergio@comunico-1266.iam.gserviceaccount.com" ) 
                .setServiceAccountScopes( Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS) )
                .setServiceAccountUser( "otticanet.ad@gmail.com" )
                .setClientSecrets( clientSecrets )
                .build();
        return credential;
    }
    public static Gmail getGmailService() throws Exception {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Gmail.Builder( HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential )
                .setApplicationName( APPLICATION_NAME )
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Gmail service = getGmailService();
            String user = "me";
            ListLabelsResponse listResponse =service.users().labels().list(user).execute();
            List<Label> labels = listResponse.getLabels();
            if (labels.size() == 0) { System.out.println("No labels found."); } 
            else {
                System.out.println("Labels:");
                for (Label label : labels) {
                    System.out.printf("- %s\n", label.getName());
                }
            }
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my maven pom dependencies list :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-services-gmail</artifactId>
      <version>v1-rev40-1.21.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

That generate this dependencies set :

```
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/com/google/apis/google-api-services-gmail/v1-rev40-1.21.0/google-api-services-gmail-v1-rev40-1.21.0.jar
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/com/google/api-client/google-api-client/1.21.0/google-api-client-1.21.0.jar
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/com/google/oauth-client/google-oauth-client/1.21.0/google-oauth-client-1.21.0.jar
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/com/google/http-client/google-http-client/1.21.0/google-http-client-1.21.0.jar
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpclient/4.0.1/httpclient-4.0.1.jar
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.0.1/httpcore-4.0.1.jar
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/commons-codec/commons-codec/1.3/commons-codec-1.3.jar
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/1.3.9/jsr305-1.3.9.jar
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/com/google/http-client/google-http-client-jackson2/1.21.0/google-http-client-jackson2-1.21.0.jar
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.1.3/jackson-core-2.1.3.jar
/home/sbelli/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava-jdk5/17.0/guava-jdk5-17.0.jar
```

This is my JSON credential file (downloaded from Google Developer Console) :

```
    {
    "installed":{
     "client_id":"my_client_id_x",
     "project_id":"my_project_id",
     "auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
     "token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
     "auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs"
     }
    }
```

When i run my example class i obtain this issue :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.<init>(GoogleCredential.java:317)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.build(GoogleCredential.java:515)
    at it.trew.comunico.business.test.ComunicoTestSergio.authorize(ComunicoTestSergio.java:51)
    at it.trew.comunico.business.test.ComunicoTestSergio.getGmailService(ComunicoTestSergio.java:55)
    at it.trew.comunico.business.test.ComunicoTestSergio.main(ComunicoTestSergio.java:63)
```

If i comment the lines :

- .setServiceAccountId( "comunico-test-sergio comunico-test-sergio@comunico-1266.iam.gserviceaccount.com" )
- .setServiceAccountScopes( Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS) )
- .setServiceAccountUser( "otticanet.ad@gmail.com" )

i obtain the issue

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
{
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Login Required",
    "reason" : "required"
  } ],
  "message" : "Login Required"
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at it.trew.comunico.business.test.ComunicoTestSergio.main(ComunicoTestSergio.java:65)
```

What's the matter?! I follow step by step the online tutorial... :(

Every help is appreciate!

Comment: your Json file looks like Oauth2 credentials. your code says service account.  What did you create on the Google Developers console and what should you have created?   can you add a link to the tutorial you are following the Gmail quick start I found for java doesn't contain the service account code you have there.

Comment: Hi DalmTo, i follow some online tutorial :

Comment: 1) https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java#prerequisites
2) https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#overview
3) https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/about-auth#why_use_google_for_authentication
4) https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server#create_a_client_id_and_client_secret

Comment: ant this for the correct set of libraries : 
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/gmail/v1#add-library-to-your-project

Comment: JSON credential are of the OAuth 2.0 client ID, but i have also registered a service account key...

Comment: my goal is to obtain server to server authentication because i have to read gmail messages in a batch job.

Answer (score 0):

Before you should jump into using service accounts.. here are a few questions.

1. Is this app going to access just your gmail account or a lot of users?
2. How are those users authorizing this app?
   2a. If app is used by a  company then an admin can authorize a set of users.
   2b. If app is used by individual users then they should authorize it through Oauth approval flow.

> ```
>            .setServiceAccountId( "comunico-test-sergio comunico-test-sergio@comunico-1266.iam.gserviceaccount.com" ) 
>             .setServiceAccountScopes( Arrays.asList(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS) )
>             .setServiceAccountUser( "otticanet.ad@gmail.com" )
> ```

In your example you created a service account and are trying to access emails of otticanet.ad@gmail.com. How did otticanet.ad@gmail.com authorize the service account to grant access? It probably didn't.
For 2a, a service account makes more sense. For 2b, you should be getting the user through oauth approval flow and get a code and exchange it for a refresh/access token and use it for the apis.